# Problem Loading ZoeDepth Model in Jetson Orin Nano

Tags: python

I am trying to load the ZoeDepth model in Jetson Orin Nano. But I am getting this error.

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ZoeDepthNK:

```
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.0.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.1.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.2.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.3.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.4.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.5.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.6.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.7.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.8.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.9.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.10.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.11.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.12.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.13.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.14.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.15.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.16.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.17.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.18.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.19.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.20.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.21.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.22.attn.relative_position_index", "core.core.pretrained.model.blocks.23.attn.relative_position_index".
```

I've tried same thing on my local PC, it works properly. Both the machines are running same Torch and Torchvision versions.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release detials; you mention a Jetson Orin Nano which comes with a Ubuntu based system that includes a lot of Debian packages too (ie. *it's not a Ubuntu system, only Ubuntu based for parts*), so what are you running? and why ask here?